# What is the easiest way to get the "Give Him the Stick" achievement?

Tags: achievements, homefront

I'm trying to achievement hunt Homefront and some of the achievements are pretty hard to get. It's also very tedious because every mission has multiple achievements to do. I've completed almost every achievement for mission 1 other than the Iron Man challenge and the melee 25 troops one. What's the easiest and quickest strategy for this?